# Full text search through many tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, full-text-search, nosql, rdbms

We have high traffic NEWS websites, I want to add a feature that every user can search through over all content of site, such as `news`, `polls`, `comments`, `galleries`,etc . Each of contents type has its own table(s).

I decided to create a table that holds all of contents from all types:

```
CREATE TABLE full_text_search
(
    master_id INT NOT NULL,
    content_text TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( master_id )
);
```

I generate a unique number as `master_id` for each content of all types to identify each `content_text` in `full_text_search` table.

for example:

```
News table:
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+------------+
| id | news_title  | lead    | subtitle|  content | master_id  |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+------------+
|  1 |  sometitle  |some lead| subtitle|content 1 |     3      |
|  2 |  some title |some lead| subtitle|content 2 |     5      |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+------------+

article table:
+----+-------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------+
| id | title       | author  | short description| content | master_id  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------+
|  1 |  sometitle  | someone | very short desc  |content1 |     1      |
|  2 |  some title | otherone|  some short desc |content2 |     4      |
+----+-------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------+
```

As you can see `master_id` is unique between above tables. When ever a new content from each type inserted, also I should `INSERT` it in to `full_text_search` table.

### QUESTIONS

- For many inserts for a day(about 3000 from all types), is it a good solution or it is anti pattern?
- Is it better choice if I separate this table from my other tables, and put it in any other DB such as other RDBMS or NoSQLs?
- Any other solutions?

Comment: With the `full_text_search`-table, how will you identify the correct result with the correct type and id?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's fine to copy the searchable content to your full_text_search table.

MySQL supports FULLTEXT indexes only in the MyISAM storage engine (until MySQL 5.6, but fulltext in InnoDB in MySQL 5.6 still seems a little unstable).  So you can store your canonical data in InnoDB for safety, and a copy in MyISAM for indexing.  MyISAM is susceptible to data corruption, but if it's only a copy then you just need to repopulate the MyISAM table if it ever gets corrupted.

Your use of master_id as distinct from the primary key of each table is a little strange.  Why not use the primary key, and add another column to your full_text_search table for the type of content?

```
CREATE TABLE full_text_search
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    content_type ENUM('news','polls','comments','galleries','articles') NOT NULL,
    content_text TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id, content_type )
);

full_text_search table:
+----+--------------+---------------+
| id | content_type | content_text  |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 |         news |     ...       |
|  1 |     articles |     ...       |
|  2 |     articles |     ...       |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

Another option is to create a fulltext search index in another specialized technology such as Sphinx Search or Apache Solr.  But the same pattern would be useful -- store the primary key field *and* a field for the type of content.

Comment: I have read your book `SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming`. In "Polymorphic Associations" section you said in MySQL we can't have polymorphic association, in I want to have foreign key for this table I should have "a Common Super-Table",the master_id is the id generated by this common super-table.

Comment: Then why not use that master_id as the primary key in each of the media tables, like the examples I show in my book?  :-)  The good reason to do that is the fact that primary key lookups are more efficient than secondary key lookups in the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: Looking at doing this myself so I can do a fulltext search by combining data from many tables. Creating a new table seems to be the answer.